# I'm trying to make an id searcher which does a thing when you input the right id. However, the if statement always runs. Why is this?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, comparison-operators

I'm trying to make an id searcher which does a thing when you input the right id in google scripts. However, the if statement always runs. Why is this?
The code is here:

```
function change() 
{  
    var a = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Sheet1!A7")
    var b = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Sheet1!B7")
    var c = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Sheet1!C7")
    var d = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Sheet1!D7")

    a.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Sheet1!M4"))
    b.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Sheet1!N4"))
    c.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Sheet1!O4"))
    d.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Sheet1!P4"))

    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Sheet1!M4").setBackground("white")
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Sheet1!N4").setBackground("white")
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Sheet1!O4").setBackground("white")
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("Sheet1!P4").setBackground("white")
}


function myFunction() 
{
    var id  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveCell()
    var idx = id.getValue()

    if (idx = 91360136) 
    {
        change()
    }
    else { id = "invalid id" }
}
```

Nothing shows up in the debugger at all.

Comment: How about modifying from ``idx = 91360136`` to ``idx == 91360136``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Apps Script use [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), on it a single `=` is used to assign a primitive or object to a variable. Use `==` to do an abstract equality comparison or `===` to do a strict equality comparison.

Change

```
if (idx = 91360136) {
```

to

```
if (idx === 91360136) {
```

Related Q&A

- [Using onEdit in Google Spreadsheets to edit cell contents live](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15978057/1595451)
- [How to set a variable based on other variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49590632/1595451)

Comment: @Someonewhoisstilllearning Please edit your question to add more details like the execution transcript and what did you see when using the debugger. See [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting) for details about this tools.